# Get device name from PCIE slot number

Tags: linux, pci-e

I have 4 SSD cards plugged into my system. They show up as /dev/nvme[0-3]n1.

Using lspci -vvv I can get the PCIE slot numbers of these 4 cards. But how to match the PCIE slot number with the device name? For example one of the cards has the slot number 3b:00:0. What is the corresponding /dev/nvme[0-3]n1?

I have gone through /sys/bus/pci/devices but not found what I'm looking for. Google has not thrown up any answers either.

TIA
cheers

Comment: For a one time shot, try looking at the resulting file from `sudo lshw -html > ~/Desktop/hardware_file.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try searching for device name somewhat like this:

```
grep "3b:00.0" /sys/class/nvme/*/device/uevent
```

Then you will need to extract device name from the output:

```
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0n1/device/uevent:PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:3b:00.0
```

This will be the string in place of the asterisk.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!